# The n-th "Invalid parent value" error

Tags: jags

I hope you can help me with a very simple model I'm running right now in Rjags.
The data I have are as follows:

```
> print(data)
$R
225738      184094       66275       24861       11266
228662      199379       70308       27511       12229
246808      224814       78255       30447       13425
254823      236063       83099       33148       13961
263772      250706       89182       35450       14750
272844      262707       96918       37116       15715
280101      271612      102604       38692       16682
291493      283018      111125       40996       18064
310474      299315      119354       44552       19707
340975      322054      126901       47757       21510
347597      332946      127708       49103       21354
354252      355994      130561       51925       22421
366818      393534      140628       56562       23711
346430      400629      146037       59594       25313
316438      399545      150733       62414       26720
303294      405876      161793       67060       29545

$N
9597000     8843000     9154000     9956000    11329000
9854932     9349814     9532373    10195193    11357751
9908897     9676950     9303113    10263930    11141510
9981879     9916245     9248586    10270193    10903446
10086567    10093723     9307104    10193818    10660101
10242793    10190641     9479080    10041145    10453320
10434789    10222806     9712544     9835154    10411620
10597293    10238784    10014422     9611918    10489448
10731326    10270163    10229259     9559334    10502839
10805148    10339566    10393532     9625879    10437809
10804571    10459413    10466871     9800559    10292169
10696317    10611599    10477448    10030407    10085603
10540942    10860363    10539271    10245334     9850488
10411836    11053751    10569913    10435763     9797028
10336667    11152428    10652017    10613341     9850533
10283624    11172747    10826549    10719741     9981814

$n
[1] 16

$na
[1] 5

$pbeta
[1] 0.70 0.95
```

and the model is as follows:

```
cat('model{
## likelihoods ##
for(k in 1:na){ for(w in 1:n){ R[w,k] ~ dbin( theta[w,k], N[w,k] ) }}

for(k in 1:na){ for(w in 1:n){ theta[w,k]  <- 0.5*beta[w,k]*0.5 }}

for(k in 1:na){
    beta[1,k] ~ dunif(pbeta[1], pbeta[2])           
    beta.plus[1,k] <- beta[1,k]                             
    for (w in 2:n){                             
    beta.plus[w,k] ~ dunif(beta[(w-1),k], 0.95)             
    beta[w,k] <- beta.plus[w,k]} } }',
file='model1.bug')

######## initial random values for beta
bbb=bb.plus=matrix(rep(NA, 16*5), byrow=T, ncol=5);  
for(k in 1:5){ 
    bbb[1,k]=runif(1, 0.7,0.95); 
    for (w in 2:16){ 
        bb.plus[w,k] = runif(1, bbb[w-1,k], 0.95); 
        bbb[w,k]=bb.plus[w,k]} }

## data & initial values
inits1 <- list('beta'= bbb )

jags_mod <- jags.model('model1.bug', data=data, inits=inits1, n.chains=1, n.adapt=1000)
update(jags_mod, n.iter=1000)
posts=coda.samples(model=jags_mod,variable.names=c('beta','theta'), n.iter=niter, thin=1000)
```

Super easy. This is actually a scaled down model from a more complex one which gives me exactly the same error message I get here.
Whenever I run this model, no problems at all. 
You will notice that the priors for parameter beta are written in such a way to be increasing from 0.7 to 0.95.

Now I would like to "shut off" the likelihood for R by commenting out the first line of the model. I'd like to do so, to see how the parameter theta gets estimated in any case (basically I should find theta=beta/4 in this case, but that would be fine with me)

When I do that, I get an "Invalid parent" error for parameter beta, generally in the bottom rows (rows 15 or 16) of the matrix.
Actually it's more sophisticated than this: sometimes I get an error, and sometimes I don't (mostly, I do).

I don' t understand **why this happens**: shouldn't the values of beta generated independently from the presence/absence of a likelihood?

Sorry if this is a naive question, I really hope you can help me sort it out.
Thanks, best!
Emanuele

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with the model a bit more I think I found the cause of your problem. One necessary aspect of the uniform distribution (i.e., `unif(a,b)`) is that `a`<`b`. When you are making the uniform distribution smaller and smaller within your model you are bringing `a` closer and closer to `b`. At times, it does not reach it, but other times `a` equals `b` and you get the invalid parent values error.  For example, in your model if you include:

```
example ~ dunif(0.4,0.4)
```

You will get "Error in node example, Invalid parent values".

So, to solve this I think it will be easier to adjust how you specify your priors instead of assigning them randomly.  You could do this with the beta distribution. At the first step, `beta(23.48, 4.98)` covers most of the range from 0.7 to 0.95, but we could truncate it to make sure it lies between that range. Then, as `n` increases you can lower 4.98 so that the prior shrinks towards 0.95. The model below will do this. After inspecting the priors, it does turn out that `theta` does equal `beta/4`.

```
data.list <- list( n = 16, na = 5,
                   B = rev(seq(0.1, 4.98, length.out = 16))) 

cat('model{
## likelihoods ##
    #for(k in 1:na){ for(w in 1:n){ R[w,k] ~ dbin( theta[w,k], N[w,k] ) }}

    for(k in 1:na){ for(w in 1:n){ theta[w,k]  <- 0.5*beta[w,k]*0.5 }}
    for(k in 1:na){
    for(w in 1:n){
    beta[w,k] ~ dbeta(23.48, B[w]) T(0.7,0.95)           

    } } }',
    file='model1.bug')

jags_mod <- jags.model('model1.bug', data=data.list, 
inits=inits1, n.chains=1, n.adapt=1000)

update(jags_mod, n.iter=1000)

posts=coda.samples(model=jags_mod,
variable.names=c('beta','theta'), n.iter=10000, thin=10)
```

Looking at some of the output from this model we get

```
     beta[1,1] theta[1,1]
[1,] 0.9448125  0.2362031
[2,] 0.7788794  0.1947198
[3,] 0.9498806  0.2374702

0.9448125/4
[1] 0.2362031
```

Since I don't really know what you are trying to use the model for I do not know if the beta distribution would suit your needs, but the above method will mimic what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
I'm afraid this is not yet working properly, because  when I set `bbb` in the data and then use the `make_inits` function to generate the initial values for `beta` in the chain, I get the same error.

The weird thing is that when I have the likelihood in the model, it *never* makes that kind of error. 
It's still unclear why...

Thanks, anyway!
EM

Comment: I played around with the model a little bit more to see what was going on. I was on the right track but off by a bit. I figured out your problem and have I edited my answer with an additional solution that will hopefully be helpful.